# Drain BlockingQueue when full

Tags: java, multithreading

I would like to know what is the best way to drain a `BlockingQueue` when it become full.

I store `String`s in a `BlockingQueue` with a capacity of 10.

Some Threads put `String`s in it.
And a Thread must be run when the Queue is full, to drain it.

So, please tell me if i'm right to use a `BlockingQueue` for that, and is there a way to run my Thread when the queue is full ?

Comment: You should remove entries from it whenever you can process them. Leaving it until it is full is just literally a waste of time.

Comment: @EJP Ok I keep that in mind. Thanks. In fact, I had misunderstood how to use BlockingQueue, now it's much more clear to me. (After hours of reading docs.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If this really is what you want, you could use Google Guava's [`Queues.drain()`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Queues.html#drain-java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue-java.util.Collection-int-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-) with an appropriate (infinite?) timeout:

```
Queues.drain(queue, buffer, 10, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

This will wait for 10 elements or 1 minute, whichever happens first.

---

That said, you can always simply not wait for the whole queue to fill up, but take elements eagerly and buffer them yourself with something similar to this:

```
while (true) {
    E element = queue.take();
    buffer.add(element);
    if (buffer.size() == 10) {
        doSomethingWithElements(buffer);
        buffer.clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't know about this `Queue.drain()` function. I'll try to use it. Thanks for both codes very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your use case correctly you need thread safe way of adding to queue. I would suggest using ConcurrentLinkedQueue. BlockingQueue will block your thread when size is equal to 0. As for draining it. When adding new item to the queue check if there is free space, if not start new Thread to drain it.

Answer (score -1):

yes you can use blockingqueue just be sure about the method you use to enqueue and dequeue because they have a different behaviour when the queue is f.e. empty/full (have a look at the link below)
one way to do it is to use a thread which checks with the method remainingCapacity() if it is equal to 0 and then block the queue or just dequeue 10 elements concurrently while other thread are still enqueueing, depending on you desire

for further information have a look in the java doc https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html